# Dual boot wifi issues 16.04LTS

Tags: networking, dual-boot

I have installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC and
my problem is weak internet speed while using WiFi on Ubuntu. On Windows machine it is something around 250Mb/s
but on the Ubuntu it is ~ 20 Mb/s. 
I don't know how to fix it, I had found similar problems and tried solutions for them, but none of them work. Here is my network info:
https://pastebin.com/PVB6ECme

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: what have you tried so far? the thing on pastebin is just a paste of the script itself, not the output from running it, which is what we need.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Alraeady updated link

I have tried setting 'prefer IPv4', adding some entries to blacklist, changing parameter of 11n_disable, setting my region..

Comment: May seem obvious, but have you double-checked that you're connected to your own WiFi and not your next door neighbour's?

Comment: I'm just taking a shot in the dark here, since I don't have personal experience with your hardware, but the problem may be related to your firmware. According to Intel's Linux support site for wireless adapters, the firmware required for your adapter (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265) is iwlwifi v 25.30.14.0 (iwlwifi-3160-ucode.25.30.14.0), but I don't see that one listed in your pastebin. Instead you have iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode. You can see that this the version loaded by your kernel in line 721: `iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.608620.0 op_mode iwlmvm`

Comment: Also, if you try booting into an older kernel (like 4.4.0-xxx), do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Here's a link to the [Intel support site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)

Comment: @Emily I downloaded firmware you had mention and copied this to /lib/firmware.

But after reboot kernel still loads old firmware, so i changed name of it by adding postfix '.bak' and my dosn't work.

Comment: @JimDeadlock I am connected to proper network.